# Calling the .name method does not return the object's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the category object to return the name "Comedy", but is returning "Category" instead when I call the name method. Not sure where to look to solve this issue so I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

pry response from command link:

```
[17] pry(#<QueueItem>)> category
=> [#<Category id: 1, name: "Comedy", created_at: "2014-03-17 19:21:34", updated_at: "2014-03-17 19:21:34">]
[18] pry(#<QueueItem>)> category.name
=> "Category"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your `QueveItem#category` method? It seems it returns relation instead of single object.

Comment: Show the source of `QueueItem` class, as it seems to be the source of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above code and output, it seems like, category variable is storing an array of category ActiveRecord Objects. So we need to use the object by the following code.

```
category.first.name
```

Comment: It's not an array. `Array` class doesn't have `name` method implemented at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, if we try on console `category.class` we should get:

```
> category.class
# ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Category
```

That's why it didn't throw Error, undefined method `name` for Array, simply because it is not an Array, and  [Rails Active Record Relations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) do have a name method

Actually, i never used `pry` but default rails console would have dumped the class name before the data:

```
> category
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, ....>, #<Category id:2 ...>, .. etc]
```

Which is really useful.